# Bash pass all arguments from function to command except for the last one

Tags: bash, arguments, parameter-passing

```sh
myfunc ()
{
    if [${*: -1} == "some argument"]
    then
        command anotherCommand "$@"
    elif [ ... ] 
        ...
    fi
}
```

How can I change `"$@"` so it passed all arguments to `anotherCommand` **except the last one?**

Comment: Why not change the interface so that the argument to examine is the *first* argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your script to :

```
myfunc ()
{
    if [${*: -1} == "some argument"]
    then
        command anotherCommand "${@:1:$#-1}"
    elif [ ... ] 
        ...
    fi
}
```

And you effectively will pop the last parameter.

EXAMPLE :

```
#!/bin/bash


myfunc ()
{
    echo "${@:1:$#-1}"
}

myfunc apple orange banana watermelon
```

PRINTS

```
$ ./some.sh 
apple orange banana
```

Comment: Your answer is popping both the first and the last argument. You can verify this with `bash -c 'echo "${@:1:$#-1}"' arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 --> arg2 arg3`

Comment: cat 1.sh 
if [[ $1 == "1" ]];
    then
        echo $@
else
echo "${@:1:$#-1}"
    fi

bash 1.sh 11 22 33
11 22
bash 1.sh 1 22 33
1 22 33

Comment: @AdamGriffiths I added an example which you can run in your terminal. Its working for me. Let me know if it works

Comment: @AdamGriffiths if you do  bash -c 'echo $@' arg1 arg2 you can see it drops arg1 anyway

Comment: @AdamGriffiths I think it might be because the first argument is usually the path to the current process, and is different for functions. But I am not sure. Someone might correct.

Answer (score 1):

Change `myfunc` so that the key argument comes *first*, then you can simply write

```
myfunc () {
   first=$1
   shift
   if [ "$first" = "some argument" ]; then
       command anotherCommand "$@"
   elif [ ... ]; then
       ...
   fi
}
```

Or, if there's some reason you need all of the original arguments in `$@` in later branches, you can move the `shift` into the `if` statement:

```
if [ "$first" == "some argument" ]; then
    shift
    command anotherCommand "$@"
elif ...
```